# Volume of an evolving set

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, calculus-of-variations

Given a set $ \Omega \subset \mathrm{R}^n$ with smooth boundary I consider a family of sets $ \Omega(t)$, $t>0$ small, such that
$ \partial \Omega(t) = \{ g(x,t): x \in \partial \Omega \}$. Here $g$ is given by
$$
g(x,t) = \nu(x)(h_1(x)t+h_2(x)t^2)
$$
Here $\nu$ is the normal vectorfield on $ \partial \Omega$ and $h_1(x),h_2(x) \in C^{\infinity}(\partial \Omega)$.
Using the formulae for the first and second variation of volume 
$$
vol(\Omega(t))'= \int_{\partial \Omega}< X_0, \nu> \,d\mu_{\partial \mu}
$$
$$
vol(\Omega(t))'= \int_{\partial \Omega} < X_0, \nu>' + < X_0, \nu> div_{\partial \Omega} X   \,d\mu_{\partial \mu}
$$
where $F:(-\epsilon, \epsilon)\times R^n \to R^n$ is the variation such that $F(t, \Omega)= \Omega(t) $ and $\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}=X_t$ I was able to prove
$$
vol(\Omega(t)) = vol(\Omega) + \int_{\partial \Omega} th_1(x)+ \frac{t^2}{2}(h_1(x)+ 2h_2(x)) dx + \mathcal{O}(t^3).
$$
But what I am in fact interested in is 
$$
vol(\Omega(t)\backslash \Omega).
$$
I suspect that we have
$$
vol(\Omega(t)\backslash \Omega) = \int_{\partial \Omega} (th_1(x)+ \frac{t^2}{2}(h_1(x)+ 2h_2(x)))_+ dx
$$
where $(...)_+$ is the positive part. 
Does anyone have an idea how I could prove this?

Comment: What are the domain and codomain of $g$? What is $f$, and how is it related to $g$?

Comment: There are classic Steiner formulas and Quermassintegrale formulas in integral geometry for the case of tubular neighborhoods. But I'm confused. If we take $\Omega$ to be a ball of radius $1$ and consider linear expansion in the radial direction, then $g(x,t) = (1+t)x$. So what is $f$ in this case? And do you really get $\mathscr O(t^3)$?

Comment: @Jack Lee The function $g$ is defined on the boundary $\partial \Omega$I edited it for further details regarding the relation between $f$ and $g$.

Comment: @ Ted Shifrin I have $0(t^3) $ because I computed the second and third Taylor coefficients of the volume. Both are integrals of functions depending on the function $g$. Do you have a reference for these formulas? For $g(x,t)=(1+x)t$ we would have $f(x,t)=t+t^2/2$.